# Cauchy inequality $\Rightarrow$ Schwarz's integral inequality. Why can't the limit of the prior be used to deduce the latter?

Tags: limits, fake-proofs, integral-inequality

Given the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the Riemann definition for the integral,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k\le\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2}$$
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$

why can you not simply put the two together
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k\le\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2}\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2}$$

$$a_k=f \left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\sqrt{\frac{b-a}{n}},b_k=g \left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\sqrt{\frac{b-a}{n}}$$
($a_k,b_k$ depends on $n$) to get
$$\int_a^bg(x)f(x)dx\le \sqrt{\int_a^bf(x)^2dx}\sqrt{\int_a^bg(x)^2dx}$$
? It appears that this simple-minded method is incorrect, for example, here's a passage from [page 11](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/CSMC_StartingWithCauchy.pdf) of Michael Steele's book:

> [This] approach to [the integral inequality] via Cauchy’s inequality would have been
>   problematical for several reasons, including the fact that the *strictness
>   of a discrete inequality can be lost in the limiting passage to integrals*.

Could some kind person explain why this is: in general and in this particular case (at which point did the above 'derivation' run afoul)?

Comment: $a_k$ in your definition depends on $n$. Better to make that explicit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As to your deleted comment, does the above not assume continuity of $f(x),g(x)$ (I don't know whether it was that or trying not to confuse me with the general case)?

Comment: I couldn't quite figure it out. It definitely doesn't work for general Lebesque integrals, but I think this specific approach also doesn't work for all Riemann-integrable $f,g$, but it has been a long time since I can recall the unusual cases, so I dropped the comment.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm unlikely to use discontinuous functions in the near future, so it's not a problem for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is right, the issue is the following:

If

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k < \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2}$$

you only get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k\le\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2}\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k^2} $$

It is possible to have $c_n < d_n$ and $\lim c_n = \lim d_n$.

That paragraph refers to the fact that Schwartz needed to find/use the equality case in the CS.

So, you can extend the standard CS inequality by Riemann Sums, but you cannot characterize this way the equality case....